# What productId should I use purchases.subscriptions.acknowledge method?

Tags: android, android-billing

I wanted to acknowledge a subscription purchase made by user.

According to [Google docs](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/acknowledge) I have to send a **subscriptionID**, but according to [purchases.subscriptionsv2.get](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptionsv2/get) it may return more than one line item, each line item contains its own **subscriptionId** (productId)

The question is, which **subscriptionId** should I use in "acknowledge" if a purchase has more than one line items with different **subscriptionId**?

From the Doc it's not clear what to do.

Comment: You may want to have a look here how to do that: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#process

Answer (score 0):

I too have the same problem.  I found the following description on the developer page, so I will paste it.

lineItems[0].productId: This field replaces subscriptionId from previous versions

link:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/compatibility

I hope you find it useful.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).